# $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ is reflexive. Need help understanding the proof.

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that every finite dimensional normed space is reflexive, so this would imply X is reflexive.

However, the author writes that this also follows directly from the fact that the second dual of $X$ is the space itself.

I'm failing to relate how $X$ isomorphic to $X''$ and reflexivity of $X$ are one and the same thing.

We are defining a space $X$ to be reflexive when the the range of the canonical map $C: X \to X''$ is the space $X''$, that is when $C$ is surjective.

So more specifically, if I understand the definition and everything we've studies previously correctly, $X$ is reflexive when $C$ is an isomorphism. However, when we proved the dual space of $X$ is $X$ (hence also the second dual), we were't dealing with the canonical map. Is this then correct to say that just because $X$ is isomrphic to $X''$, they would also be isomorphic under $C$ as well and hence $X$ is reflexive?

Edit: While the answer below is greatly appreciated, I would like it if someone can answer the more specific questions I've asked above to help clear up the conceptual misunderstandings I have.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical map $C$ is always injective. Let $X$ have basis $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$. If $v = \sum_{i=i}^nv_ie_i$ and $C(v)(\alpha) = \alpha(v) = 0$ for all $\alpha \in X'$, then taking $\alpha = \delta_j$ (the corresponding basis functional) gives $v_j =0$ for all $j$. Hence $v=0$. Then the fact that $X = X''$ shows that $C$ is an isomorphism, by comparing dimensions.